# Installed with pip3 modules no longer recognizable. Need to reinstall with pip

Tags: python, pip

I faced a strange issue: I'm working on a Python/Flask project on my local computer, don't use the virtual env. I installed different modules with **pip3**, like Flask-SQLAlchemy, Flask-Migrate, etc. Everything worked perfectly.
Suddenly, after a few weeks, when running the program, it started to appear the errors, like `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'` - and the same for Flask-Migrate, Flask-WTF, etc.

The solution is to install all these modules again but with **pip** (not pip3). Uninstallation/Installation with pip3 does not help. Why did it happen? Is it possible to turn it back to pip3?

I didn't change the environment, I have the only one actually. Using Python 3.8

Comment: Why would you not work with virtual environments? This is one of the reasons why they exist... For the issue that you have I wonder, how do you run your application?

Comment: flask run - when I run it locally

Comment: You can try to run it like this: `python3.8 -m flask run`, then with this command you explicitly say which python version `Flask` should use and at the same moment you will use libraries installed with `pip3`, but still, I would say that you really need to start using virtual environments and then you will not have these issues, because still even with this line you might get errors due to clash of some libraries that you have installed with `pip3` for different projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the reason why it is like this, it's because maybe there is some libraries for other your projects that clash with flask libraries and that's why you have issues. E.g. I had the same issue when I didn't use virtual environments when I was learning Python, and when I had multiple projects with different python libraries, some of them clashed and produced unexpected errors, so I started using virtual environments - different virtual environment for each project and it solved all the problems with clashes between different libraries.

Here is a good official [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) on how to use virtual environments

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I should get used to the virtual environments finally :)